# Google Apps Script - Sheets - IF statement with INCLUDES

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying create a script that copies a row depending on what is in Column E. If the column has "CORE" , "WARRANTY", or contains "DAMAGE" it would be copied.  I have figure out the  "CORE" and "WARRANTY" portion in the code below, but I am not sure how to use INCLUDES:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "MAIN" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == "CORE"  || r.getValue() == "WARRANTY" || r.includes("DAMAGE")) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ELITE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no range.include and I wouldn't use r.getValue() instead I would use event.value.  So it would be ( event.value === "CORE" ) for example and ( event.value.indexOf("DAMAGE") >= 0 ).  onEdit(event) triggers when the user edits a cell.  The event object includes information about the cell that was editted, its range and value.  In your case the event.value is a string so use the string method indexOf to search if the value contains a substring.

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code it what I ended up working:

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "MAIN" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == "CORE"  || r.getValue() == "WARRANTY" || event.value.indexOf("DAMAGE") >= 0) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ELITE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned above I would use event.value instead of r.getValue().  event is an object in memory, getValue() is a call to the server to get a value.  event.value is much faster then getValue().